# skimage project an image's 3D plane to fronto-parallel view

Tags: geometry, projection, scikit-image

I'm working on implementing Akush Gupta's synthetic data generation dataset (http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/scenetext/gupta16.pdf). In his work. he used a convolutional neural network to extract a point cloud from a 2-dimensional scenery image, segmented the point clouds to isolate different planes, used RANSAC to fit a 3d plane to the point cloud segments, and then warped the pixels for the segment, given the 3D plane, to a fronto-parallel view.

I'm stuck in this last part- warping my extracted 3D plane to a fronto-parallel view. I have X, Y, and Z vectors as well as a normal vector. I'm thinking what I need to do is perform some type of perspective transform or rotation that would bring all the pixels on the plane to a complete 0 Z-axis while the X and Y would remain the same. I could be wrong about this, it's been a long time since I've had any formal training in geometry or linear algebra.

It looks like skimage's Perspective Transform requires me to know the dimensions of the final segment coordinates in 2d space. It looks like AffineTransform requires me to know the rotation. All I have at this point is my X,Y,Z and normal vector and the suspicion that I may know my destination plane by just setting the Z axis to all zeros. I'm not sure if my assumption is correct but I need to be able to warp all the pixels in the segment of interest to fronto-parallel, fit a bounding box, place text inside of it, then warp the final segment back to the original perspective in 3d space.

Any help with how to think about this or implement it would be massively useful.